# How can I reset timer0?

Tags: c, timer, atmel, avr-gcc, atmelstudio

my microcontroller is attiny85.Actually I have a few questions.
I simply turn on the LED 8 seconds later with the code below.

1)Should I turn the interrupts off and on while reading the counter value? I've seen something like this in the wiring.c file, the millis function.

2)How can I safely set the counter variable to 0 whenever I want? Do I have to turn the interrupts off and on here? Should I set the variables TCCR0A, TCCR0A, TCNT0 to zero?How should a safe reset function be?

Actually, all my purpose is to make a safe counter in the main function that can count 8 seconds whenever I want and start from zero whenever I want.

My basic code in below :

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

volatile unsigned int counter = 0;


ISR(TIM0_COMPA_vect){ 
    //interrupt commands for TIMER 0 here
    counter++;
}



void timerprogram_init()     
{
// TIMER 0 for interrupt frequency 1000 Hz:
cli(); // stop interrupts
TCCR0A = 0; // set entire TCCR0A register to 0
TCCR0B = 0; // same for TCCR0B
TCNT0  = 0; // initialize counter value to 0
// set compare match register for 1000 Hz increments
OCR0A = 124; // = 1000000 / (8 * 1000) - 1 (must be <256)
// turn on CTC mode
TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01);
// Set CS02, CS01 and CS00 bits for 8 prescaler
TCCR0B |= (0 << CS02) | (1 << CS01) | (0 << CS00);
// enable timer compare interrupt
TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);
sei(); // allow interrupts

}

int main(void)
{
    /* Replace with your application code */

    timerprogram_init();

    DDRA|=(1<<7);
    PORTA &=~ (1<<7);

    while (1)
    {
        if(counter>8000)
        PORTA |= (1<<7);

    }
  
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't really the right place to ask this. Questions here are generally more about programming with move hihg-level languages. You could try ask the same question on the Arduino stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no need to check the "counter" value in the super loop; In fact, this variable changes when an interrupt is created, so checking the variable should be done in the interrupt itself and if necessary, take only one flag from it.
Secondly, a safe way to reset the counter is to first deactivate the frequency divider(**TCCR0B**) of the timer section (the counter timer is practically turned off) and then set the **TCNT0** value to zero to reset the timer; And if necessary, you can safely force the counter timer to count by returning the divider value.
Good luck.

Comment: ,Thanks for reply.Actually, what I want to do is call functions like startimer (4000ms) and starttimer (2000ms) anywhere in my program.And getting the processor to do some work until it finishes 4000ms or 2000ms.And when the job is done, the timer should go back to the beginning as if it has never worked.

Can you give me some idea where to start?

Comment: You can use the timer to create a one millisecond cycle and count the number of overflows.
So to create a 4-second delay, you can create a function that counts up to 4,000 times counter-timer overflows; And activate a bit as a flag when the delay is over; And now our code is inside an if which is executed when this bit is set and at the end of this condition the flag bit is reset manually again.